# How to process a list of files in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, dos

I have to write a windows batch script that performs the following
take a folder as a input variable
take a list of filenames as an input variable
take an output folder as an input variable

then 
    foreach file in the list
       if filename exists in the input folder
            copy file from input folder to output folder
       else
            issue  some kind of warning

As I have never written a batch file I would really appreciate some help as I have no idea where to start

Many thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
@echo off
set /p input=Input Folder: 
set /p  output=Output Folder: 
set /p fileList= File List (file names can be separated with ;,<space>=): 

if not exist "%input%\" (
    echo input folder does not exist
    exit /b 1
)

if not exist "%output%\" (
    echo output folder does not exist
    exit /b 2
)

for %%a in (%fileList%) do (
    if exist "%input%\%%a" (
        copy /y "%input%\%%a" "%output%\" >nul 2>&1
    )
)
```

With CM parameters :

```
@echo off
set  "input=%~1" 
set "output=%~2"
::enclose the third parameter with double quotes.Separate file names with ,;<space> or =
set "fileList=%~3" 

if not exist "%input%\" (
    echo input folder does not exist
    exit /b 1
)

if not exist "%output%\" (
    echo output folder does not exist
    exit /b 2
)

for %%a in (%fileList%) do (
    if exist "%input%\%%a" (
        copy /y "%input%\%%a" "%output%\" >nul 2>&1
    )
)
```

Comment: How can I get this script to take these as parameters?

Comment: @user1414413 You want to automatize the parameters? How do you want to achieve this? Through command line parameters or through a settings file?

Comment: What is the significance of the ~

Comment: it dequotes the parameters in case they are enclosed with quotes.

Comment: @user1414413 - now you can accept the answer ,which will give me some precious points :-)